# updating php multidimensional array and resaving to db

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following structure for my array which is dynamically generated:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [friend_request_sender_id] => 1
            [friend_request_date] => 07-08-2014
            [friend_request_time] => 11:12:19
            [friend_request_recipient_id] => 5
            [friend_request_sent] => 1
            [friend_request_accepted] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [friend_request_sender_id] => 1
            [friend_request_date] => 07-08-2014
            [friend_request_time] => 11:12:47
            [friend_request_recipient_id] => 2
            [friend_request_sent] => 1
            [friend_request_accepted] => 0
        )

)
```

I would like to update the first array value `[friend_request_accepted] => 0` to this: `[friend_request_accepted] => 1` which i have achieved by doing the following:

```
$test = get_user_meta($current_user->ID,'get_user_friends', true );

    foreach($test as &$values){
    if($values['friend_request_recipient_id'] === '5'){
        $values['friend_request_accepted'] = '1';
        break; // Stop the loop after we've found the item
    }
}
```

However, i would like to actually save this new value into the database, overwriting the existing value. The array should then look like this:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [friend_request_sender_id] => 1
                [friend_request_date] => 07-08-2014
                [friend_request_time] => 11:12:19
                [friend_request_recipient_id] => 5
                [friend_request_sent] => 1
                [friend_request_accepted] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [friend_request_sender_id] => 1
                [friend_request_date] => 07-08-2014
                [friend_request_time] => 11:12:47
                [friend_request_recipient_id] => 2
                [friend_request_sent] => 1
                [friend_request_accepted] => 0
            )

    )
```

How should I do this?

Comment: What is your DB structure ? You can probably do a query to set `friend_request_accepted` to 1.

Comment: its a wordpress db, the data in the array above is a user_meta field array

Comment: @danyo You should add to your Question and your tags that you're using wordpress to clarify this Question!

Comment: @KhorneHoly i have done this in the past and got it in the neck as it wasnt a wordpress specific question. So tend to leave those tags out ;)

Answer (score 0):

this line doesn't work:

```
if($values['friend_request_recipient_id'] === '5'){
        $values['friend_request_accepted'] = '1';
        break; // Stop the loop after we've found the item
}
```

because

```
[friend_request_recipient_id] => 5
```

is an integer I think you just need to sure in condition because '===' is also checked the types of variable.